# angular ng-strict-di doesn't work with ngRoute

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

If I use `ng-strict-di` with my Angular app, and I use the `ngRoute` module, I get the error:

```
[Error] Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=epoiApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Astrictdi%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2F%24injector%2Fstrictdi%3Fp0%3Dfunction(%2524routeProvider)%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A426%0A%24%24annotate%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A182%3A482%0Ae%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A37%3A533%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A238%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A358%0An%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A306%0Ah%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A135%0A%24a%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A39%3A417%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A383%0Auc%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A180%0AUd%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A2%0Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A285%3A431%0Afire%40file%3A%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js%3A3143%3A35%0AfireWith%40file%3A%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js%3A3255%3A11%0Aready%40file%3A%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js%3A3467%3A24%0Acompleted%40file%3A%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js%3A3498%3A15
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 37)
    n (angular.min.js, line 7)
    h (angular.min.js, line 36)
    $a (angular.min.js, line 39)
    d (angular.min.js, line 18)
    uc (angular.min.js, line 19)
    Ud (angular.min.js, line 18)
    (anonymous function) (angular.min.js, line 285)
    fire (jquery.js, line 3143)
    fireWith (jquery.js, line 3255)
    ready (jquery.js, line 3467)
    completed (jquery.js, line 3498)
```

It's weird to me since `ngRoute` is an official module from Angular, isn't it? Is there a way to still use them together?

I have already included angular-route.min.js

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0-rc.0/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to inject this module while registering your application.

It is not coming with angular.js file. **ngRoute** is defined in **angular-route.js** file

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);
```

For this you have to first load `angular-route.js`

[angular-route.js](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular-route.js)

Comment: @DeLac Are you trying to add any directive or filter to ng module?

Comment: I have my custom directives... yes. `ngRoute` is not the only dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I [pasted the error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=epoiApp&p1=%5B$injector:strictdi%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2F$injector%2Fstrictdi%3Fp0%3Dfunction(%2524routeProvider)%0Ahttps:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:6:426%0A$$annotate@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:182:482%0Ae@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:37:533%0Ad@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:36:238%0Ahttps:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:36:358%0An@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:7:306%0Ah@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:36:135%0A$a@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:39:417%0Ad@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:18:383%0Auc@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:19:180%0AUd@https:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:18:2%0Ahttps:%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.4.0-rc.0%2Fangular.min.js:285:431%0Afire@file:%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js:3143:35%0AfireWith@file:%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js:3255:11%0Aready@file:%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js:3467:24%0Acompleted@file:%2F%2F%2FVolumes%2FMacintosh%2520HD%2FUsers%2FdeLac%2Fsiti%2Fepoi%2FePOI%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fjquery.js:3498:15) and got the exact error text as

> Failed to instantiate module epoiApp due to: [$injector:strictdi]
>   http:// errors.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/$injector/strictdi...)
>   https:// code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-rc.0/angular.min.js:6:426

You should include the minified version of ng-route (angular-route.min.js) to get away with this error.

There are many ways to make code minification safe, you are doing it with strict-di, ng-route might be using ng-annotate. Each library developer might use different method to make code minification safe. In the end goal of having non-breaking minified code should be achieved.

Comment: then i doubt the issue is with angular-route.. may be it is with some other lib. I am using ng-strict-di with ngRoute and there is no issue